# Using Slick Slider

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I am trying to use [this](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) slider. In this regard I wrote below code. But it is not working. I included CSS and JS files as per their instructions. Should I include jQuery here ? Can anyone help me about this ??

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href='http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.6/slick.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://vmcdn.de/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style>
        .slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before { color: black; }

        .container{padding-top:50px;}
        .client-text li {left:0;right:0;margin:auto;list-style:none;margin:50px;z-index:9999;color:black;}

        .item{ height: 200px;}
        .one {background-image: url("http://placehold.it/200&text=1"); }
        .two {background-image: url("http://placehold.it/200&text=2"); }
        .three {background-image: url("http://placehold.it/200&text=3"); }
        .four {background-image: url("http://placehold.it/200&text=4"); }
        .five {background-image: url("http://placehold.it/200&text=5"); }
        .six {background-image: url("http://placehold.it/200&text=6"); }
        .seven {background-image: url("http://placehold.it/200&text=7"); }
        .eight {background-image: url("http://placehold.it/200&text=8"); }
        .nine {background-image: url("http://placehold.it/200&text=9"); }
        .ten {background-image: url("http://placehold.it/200&text=10"); }
        .slick-slide{
          width:230px;
        margin-right: 15px;
        margin-left: 15px;
        }


        .triangle{left:0;right:0;margin:auto;width:0;
        height: 0;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 15px 15px 0 15px;
        border-color: #333333 transparent transparent transparent;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Standard carousel where Slick calculated the best widths to fit. -->
    <div class="container ">
        <div class="row ">
            <div id="carousel" class="carousel col-md-12 ">
                <div class="item one"></div>
                <div class="item two"></div>
                <div class="item three"></div>
                <div class="item four"></div>
                <div class="item five"></div>
                <div class="item six"></div>
                <div class="item seven"></div>
                <div class="item eight"></div>
                <div class="item nine"></div>
                <div class="item ten"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="triangle"></div>

            <p class="current"></p>
            <ul class="client-text">
              <li>0 lorem ipsum</li>
              <li>1 lorem ipsum</li>
              <li>2 lorem ipsum</li>
              <li>3 lorem ipsum</li>
              <li>4 lorem ipsum</li>
              <li>5 lorem ipsum</li>
              <li>6 lorem ipsum</li>
              <li>7 lorem ipsum</li>
              <li>8 lorem ipsum</li>
            </ul>
        </div>    
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.6/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://vmcdn.de/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#carousel').slick({
            arrows: true,
            slidesToShow: 3,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed:2500,
            speed: 500,
            variableWidth: true,
            onAfterChange: function(){ 
                  var cat = ($('#carousel').slickCurrentSlide()) + 1;
                  $('.client-text > li').hide();
                  $('.client-text > li:nth-child('+ cat +')').show();
            }
        });

        $('.client-text > li').hide();
        $('.client-text > li:first-child').show();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get Slick work you must include [jQuery](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js) library right before you included Slick script.